Problema al utilizar función para reemplazar valores tipo character usando R
Se tiene un DataFrame con una de sus columnas llamada "llamado_provincia", se trata de los llamados al 137 por problemas de violencia familiar o abuso sexual. Lo descargué desde datos.gob.ar/dataset/justicia-linea-137---victimas-violencia-sexual---llamados-e-intervenciones-domiciliarias
Bien, la cuestión es que en varias columnas de tipo character existen valores que figuran como "NS/NC" o "Ns/Nc" y lo que quiero es reemplazar esos valores por la moda en caso de que el porcentaje de apariciones de estos valores no supere el cinco por ciento y obviamente que la moda NO sea "NS/NC" O "Ns/Nc". Entonces si las condiciones se dan, la idea es ir reemplazando por un ranking de apariciones
de los demás valores de la columna. Por ejemplo si la provincia La Pampa aparece supongamos, en el 15% de los casos, reemplazaremos los valores "NS/NC" por "La Pampa" un 15% de veces.
El problema es que este procedimiento hay que realizarlo muchas veces porque existen muchas columnas con el mismo problema, por lo que decidí crear una función. Pero resulta que cuando  se ejecuta
la función, muy pero muy similar al código a repetir, aparece un error*, como no podía ser de otra manera.
Dejo aquí elcódigo en cuestión, primero como sería normalmente al aplicarlo a la variable y después en forma de función. Los "unique" del principio y final son para comprobar primero si existe ese
valor en esa columna y después para ver si aún persiste.
*Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Var1", value = character(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 25

NOTA: El archivo .csv se puede descargar desde https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oeJpGjtPs9ptMSwfj4iQCjGeBxPSFeUF/view?usp=drive_link
unique(df$llamado_provincia)

row_df <- nrow(df)
porcentaje <- sum(df$llamado_provincia == "NS/NC")/row_df
moda <- names(sort(table(df$llamado_provincia), decreasing = TRUE)[1])
nulos <- sum(df$llamado_provincia == "NS/NC")

if (porcentaje >= 0.05) {

  nulos <- sum(df$llamado_provincia == "NS/NC")
  ranking <- as.data.frame(table(df$llamado_provincia)) # Se crea un df con los valores char más repetidos
  ranking <- ranking %>% arrange(-Freq) # Se ordena el ranking
  ranking$Var1 <- as.character(ranking$Var1)
  row_rank <- nrow(ranking)
  flag <- F

  for (i in 1:row_rank) {                             # Aquí se lleva al útimo lugar la fila con "NS/NC"
    if (ranking$Var1[i] == "NS/NC") {                 # para luego eliminarla
      resguardo <- ranking[i, ]                       #
      flag <- T                                       #
    }                                                 #
    if (ranking$Var1[i] != "NS/NC" & flag == T) {     #
      ranking[i-1, ] <- ranking[i, ]                  #
      ranking[i, ] <- resguardo                       #
    }                                                 #
  }                                                   #

  ranking <- ranking[-c(row_rank), ]                                # Elimina la última fila, que queda en NS/NC
  ranking$porcent <- round((ranking$Freq/sum(ranking$Freq))*100, 0) # Crea una columna con el porcentaje de apariciones del valor character
  ranking$reemplazo <- round((ranking$porcent*nulos)/100, 0)        # Crea una columna con valores absolutos que van a reemplazar a "NS/NC"
  dif <- nulos - sum(ranking$reemplazo)
  ranking$reemplazo[1] <- ranking$reemplazo[1] + dif         # Como la diferencia entre valores "NS/NC" y los que van a reemplazar suele ser menor
                                                             # por redondear a cero los que están entre cero y uno en valores porcentules,
                                                             # la diferencia se le suma al valor que más haya aparecido, es decir, el que está en primer lugar 
                                                             # en el ranking

  j = 1
  for (i in 1:row_df) {
    if (df$llamado_provincia[i] == "NS/NC" & ranking$reemplazo[j] != 0) { # Se va reemplazando cada valor "NS/NC" por la cantidad de veces que haya
      df$llamado_provincia[i] <- ranking$Var1[j]                          # aparecido el valor charachter, según su posición en el ranking
      ranking$reemplazo[j] <- ranking$reemplazo[j] - 1                    #
      if (ranking$reemplazo[j] == 0) {j <- j + 1}                         #
    }                                                                     #
  }                                                                       #

} else {
  for (i in 1:row_df) {
    if (moda == "NS/NC") {
      df$llamado_provincia[i] <- ranking$Var1[1]        # Asigna el valor más repetido después de "NS/NC"
    } else if (df$llamado_provincia[i] == "NS/NC") 
    {df$llamado_provincia[i] <- moda
    }
  }
}

unique(df$llamado_provincia)

El intento de función personalizada
reemp_vble_char <- function(x, y, z) {

row_df <- nrow(x)
porcentaje <- sum(y == z)/row_df
moda <- names(sort(table(y), decreasing = TRUE)[1])
nulos <- sum(y == z)

if (porcentaje >= 0.05) {

  nulos <- sum(y == z)
  ranking <- as.data.frame(table(y)) 
  ranking <- ranking %>% arrange(-Freq) 
  ranking$Var1 <- as.character(ranking$Var1)
  row_rank <- nrow(ranking)
  flag <- F

  for (i in 1:row_rank) {                        
    if (ranking$Var1[i] == z) {                 
      resguardo <- ranking[i, ]                  
      flag <- T                                  
    }                                            
    if (ranking$Var1[i] != z & flag == T) {
      ranking[i-1, ] <- ranking[i, ]             
      ranking[i, ] <- resguardo                  
    }                                            
  }                                              

  ranking <- ranking[-c(row_rank), ]                               
  ranking$porcent <- round((ranking$Freq/sum(ranking$Freq))*100, 0)
  ranking$reemplazo <- round((ranking$porcent*nulos)/100, 0)       
  dif <- nulos - sum(ranking$reemplazo)
  ranking$reemplazo[1] <- ranking$reemplazo[1] + dif  
 
  j = 1
  for (i in 1:row_df) {
    if (y[i] == z & ranking$reemplazo[j] != 0) { 
      y[i] <- ranking$Var1[j]                    
      ranking$reemplazo[j] <- ranking$reemplazo[j] - 1
      if (ranking$reemplazo[j] == 0) {j <- j + 1}     
    }                                                 
  }                                                   

} else {
  for (i in 1:row_df) {
    if (moda == z) {
      y[i] <- ranking$Var1[1]        
    } else if (y[i] == z) 
    {y[i] <- moda
    }
  }
}
}


Resultado esperado:
Cuando se ejecuta el código en forma de función, aparece el error antes mencionado :
"Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "Var1", value = character(0)) :   replacement has 0 rows, data has 25".
Sin embargo, al ejecutarse en su forma común y corriente, el resultado es satisfactorio, no hay errores y el reemplazo se realiza sin problemas.

Me voy a enfocar en el problema y no en la solución que planteaste. Digamos que tienes un vector de valores, y hay un valor (ej. NS/NC) que quieres reemplazar por alguno de los otros valores, esto lo harías mediante los siguientes criterios:

Si la proporción del valor a reemplazar es igual o mayor al 5% se reemplazarían por el resto de los valores respetando las frecuencias de los mismos.
Si la proporción es menor usaríamos la moda (obviamente, sin considerar el valor de reemplazo)

Primero que nada, armamos un ejemplo de prueba:
provincias <- c("Buenos Aires", "Catamarca", "Chaco", "Chubut", 
                "Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "Corrientes", 
                "Entre Ríos", "Formosa", "Jujuy", "La Pampa",  "La Rioja", 
                "Mendoza", "Misiones", "Neuquén", "NS/NC", "Río Negro", "Salta", 
                "San Juan", "San Luis", "Santa Cruz", "Santa Fe", 
                "Santiago del Estero", "Tierra del Fuego", "Tucumán")

set.seed(2024)
casos <- provincias[pmin(pmax(round(rnorm(1000, mean = 13, sd = 5)), 1), 25)]

Esto genera un vector de 1000 casos, con los nombres de las 24 provincias más el "NS/NC" con una distribución normal, el valor más frecuente va a ser el que está más en el centro del vector.
Lo siguiente es que vamos a necesitar un función para calcular la moda:
moda <- function(x, useNA = "no") {
  xtabla <- table(x, useNA = useNA)             
  names(xtabla[xtabla == max(xtabla)][1])
} 

Con esto ya podemos implementar el algoritmo:
valor_reemplazo <- "NS/NC"
prop_nsnc <- proportions(table(casos))[valor_reemplazo]
prop_valores <- proportions(table(casos[casos != valor_reemplazo]))
moda_valores <- moda(casos[casos != valor_reemplazo])

if (prop_nsnc >= 0.05) {
  # imputamos los valores con la distribución del resto de las provincias
  n <- length(casos[casos==valor_reemplazo])
  valores_reemplazo <- round(prop_valores[round(prop_valores * n) > 0] * n)
  casos[casos == valor_reemplazo] <- sample(rep(names(valores_reemplazo),
                                                valores_reemplazo), n, replace = TRUE)
    
} else {
    # Reemplazamos por la moda
    casos[casos == valor_reemplazo] <- moda_valores  
  }
}

El algoritmo, prescinde del enfoque iterativo (uso de for) que tenía originalmente tú código, esto por que obviamente R lo permite y creo yo que hace todo más comprensible, simple y probablemente más "performante". El código asume que hay un único valor de reemplazo, no esta pensado para ejecutarlo múltiples veces en una misma columna con distintos valores, estaría de tu lado normalizar los valores de reemplazo en uno solo.
Transformar este código en una función es sencillo:
reemp_vble_char <- function(casos, valor_reemplazo) {

  prop_nsnc <- proportions(table(casos))[valor_reemplazo]
  prop_valores <- proportions(table(casos[casos != valor_reemplazo]))
  moda_valores <- moda(casos[casos != valor_reemplazo])
  
  if (prop_nsnc >= 0.05) {
    # imputamos los valores con la distribución del resto de las provincias
    n <- length(casos[casos==valor_reemplazo])
    valores_reemplazo <- round(prop_valores[round(prop_valores * n) > 0] * n)
    casos[casos == valor_reemplazo] <- sample(rep(names(valores_reemplazo),
                                                  valores_reemplazo), n, replace = TRUE)
    
  } else {
    # Reemplazamos por la moda
    casos[casos == valor_reemplazo] <- moda_valores  
  }
  casos
}  

Lo que sí, hay que tener en cuenta, que lo que esperaría la función es un vector, por lo que no pasaríamos un data.frame sino la columna que deseamos modificar, por ejemplo:
df$provincia <- reemp_vble_char(df$provincia, "NS/NC")

Sobre tu código
No hice un debug completo, pero puedo señalarte:

El error lo tienes en ranking$Var1 <- as.character(ranking$Var1) y es que no existe la variable Var1, entiendo que debiera reemplazarse por y en todos los caso
Por otro lado tu función no retorna ningún dato


gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para responder. Pensé que sería como una botella tirada al mar y que nadie en mucho tiempo la vería, así que nuevamente GRACIAS!
Cuando escribía el código pensaba "Bueno la optimización te la debo"... pero no pensaba que taaaanto XD.
Salud, maestro
